# How to pass enveronment variable in gitlab to setup cicd gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab

Running with gitlab-runner 14.5.2 (e91107dd)
on ibrahimrunner a8c7nx2r
Preparing the "shell" executor
00:00
Using Shell executor...
Preparing environment
00:00
Running on ip-172-31-5-177...
ERROR: Job failed: prepare environment: exit status 1. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information

I have install gitlab server in one aws ec2 and in the same server i installed gitlab-runner
now i created .gitlab-ci.yml file when i commit it automatically trigger the CICD but through above error
i.,
ERROR: Job failed: prepare environment: exit status 1. Check

Could you help me please

Answer (score 0):

According to [thus GitLab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/26605) the fix is to remove `.bash_logout`

Answer (score 0):

I was configured GitLab server and GitLab-runner machine on the same Ubuntu 20.04 machine.

But when I install GitLab-runner machine on another machine I got the solution.